# Why python launcher is not responding on macos?

Tags: python, macos

I'm new to python development and trying to run a python code script but my python launcher on mac is just keep bouncing on the dock and not running the script. Please see my code below.

```
import pyautogui
import time
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
while True:
    time.sleep(15) # in seconds
    for i in range(0, 100):
        pyautogui.moveTo(0, i * 5)
    for i in range(0, 3):
        pyautogui.press('shift')
```

Comment: How did you run your program? How would you know if it is working?

Comment: @MattDMo I'm just using iTerm and via `python main.py`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `time.sleep(15)` which means your program will sleep for 15sec. So, I think you are thinking program is not runnung. But it is running code.
I think moving `time.sleep(15)` at last would be appropriate. Like this:

```
import pyautogui
import time
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False
while True:
    for i in range(0, 100):
        pyautogui.moveTo(0, i * 5)
    for i in range(0, 3):
        pyautogui.press('shift')
    time.sleep(15) # in seconds
```

Comment: Still getting the same result.